# How to know if my program is completely started inside my docker with compose

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, docker-compose, microservices

In my CI chain I execute end-to-end tests after a "docker-compose up". Unfortunately my tests often fail because even if the containers are properly started, the programs contained in my containers are not.

Is there an elegant way to verify that my setup is completely started before running my tests ?

Comment: There's not one simple answer to this - it depends on your setup. I think the best practice nowadays is to setup health checks in your services - simple http services that run a test and respond with an Ok / not-ok reply.

Comment: Thanks for the tip ! Healthcheck seems a good way to perform what I want. However, it seems that docker-compose do not care about the health status.. So, how do you exploit it ?

Answer (score 3):

You could poll the required services to confirm they are responding before running the tests.

`curl` has inbuilt [retry logic](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--retry) or it's fairly trivial to build retry logic around some other type of service test.

```
#!/bin/bash

await(){
  local url=${1}
  local seconds=${2:-30}
  curl --max-time 5 --retry 60 --retry-delay 1 \
       --retry-max-time ${seconds} "${url}" \
  || exit 1
}

docker-compose up -d
await http://container_ms1:3000
await http://container_ms2:3000
run-ze-tests
```

The alternate to polling is an event based system. 
If all your services push notifications to an external service, [scaeda gave the example of a log file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39118838/1318694) or you could use something like Amazon SNS. Your services emit a "started" event. Then you can subscribe to those events and run whatever you need once everything has started.

Docker 1.12 did add the [`HEALTHCHECK`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/healthcheck) build command. Maybe this is available via [Docker Events](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/events/)?

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! This is the solution I had considered. That works but you have to maintain your "await scripts" and you will face the same problem in production. Instead of just doing a "docker-compose up" you'll have to create a script which launch docker-compose and await scripts.

Comment: Docker has moved away from traditional unix daemons where they could at least choose a point to background the process, and a script would continue on. mongodb is a good example of this, only doing so once it's ready to accept connections.  The alternate to polling is an event system where you push a notification from your apps to an external from they have started. Then you can subscribe to those events and act upon them.

Answer (score 2):

If you have control over the docker engine in your CI setup you could execute `docker logs [Container_Name]` and read out the last line which could be emitted by your application.

`RESULT=$(docker logs [Container_Name] 2>&1 | grep [Search_String])`

logs output example:
`Agent pid 13`
`Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): Enter same passphrase again: Identity added: id_rsa (id_rsa)`
`#host SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.6`
`#host SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.6`

parse specific line:
`RESULT=$(docker logs ssh_jenkins_test 2>&1 | grep Enter)`

result:
`Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): Enter same passphrase again: Identity added: id_rsa (id_rsa)`